# App crashing when it executes the table delegate method

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

When I run the search function in aepub reader my app crashes. It enters the cellfor row at index method and when it executes `NSLOg(@"%@",hit.neighbourText)` it shows exception.

```
    (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView1 cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView1 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }

        cell.textLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;

        NSLog(@"indexpath%d",indexPath.row);
        NSLog(@"%@",[results objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]);

        hit = (SearchResult*)[results objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

        if([results count]>0) {
            NSLog(@"%@",hit.neighboringText);
            cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"...%@...", hit.neighboringText];
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Chapter %d - page %d", hit.chapterIndex, hit.pageIndex+1];

           return cell;
        }
    }
```

I am getting some value for `hit.neighboringText` but after that, I reload my tableview then the following exception will be raised, why?

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFConstantString
>   neighboringText]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1481c4'
>       *** First throw call stack:

Comment: what is `hit` ... a big chance is that its getting nil/released/deallocated at time of accessing.

Comment: just print hit in NSLog(@"%@",hit); check whether getting nil or SearchResult object

Comment: may be `hit` is not your `modal object (SearchResult)`. try printing `NSLog("%@", [hit class]);`. If it is `String`, you've to consider looking on your `results` array.

Answer (score 5):

It's because `hit` is actually an `NSString` object and not a `SearchResult` object as you expect:

```
hit = (SearchResult*)[results objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
```

The clue is in the exception text:

```
-[__NSCFConstantString neighboringText]: unrecognized selector sent to instance ...
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

No amount of casting to `SearchResult` is going to change that.

EDIT: Actually anywhere you see a cast you should be suspicious of the actual object you are dealing with.  If you aren't sure then check it with `isKindOfClass:`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your problem lies in the error message:

> unrecognised selector sent to instance 0x1481c4.

What you need to do next is print the value of that address via po 0x1481c4.  It would appear that it is not actually a string, but you are not showing that code.

Answer (score 0):

it means that `hit = (SearchResult*)[results objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];` returns a ConstantString and not `SearchResult` object

Best would be checking if `hit` is the same class type as SearchResult before getting the value from `neighboringText`

you can try like something like this:

```
if([hit isKindOfClass:[SearchResult Class]]){
  // do something with hit
}
else{
// different class
}
```

Comment: Another way would be respondsToSelector:

Comment: Using isKindOfClass: is generally a sign that the architecture is just wrong.  There should not be cases where the type of an object is unknown until runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there are two possibilities:

- `hit` is not a `SearchResult` object but a String object
- `hit` or the `results` array is not owned anymore / released but not set to `nil` and point garbage, which I believe is the case because I have experienced it before

I think you need to make sure that the array is not autoreleased/released at that point (for example if you are creating it with `[NSArray arrayWith...]` it is autoreleased, you might not own it inside cellForRowAtIndexPath) and the hit object is properly initialized before giving it to the `results` array.